# Is (retain) required if setter is manually implemented?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, setter

I would like to know what effect (if any) does the **retain** in the following property declaration have. The manually implemented setter is retaining the variable.

Interface:

```c
@property (nonatomic, retain, setter=setIncident:) Incident * incident;
```

Implementation:

```c
- (void)setIncident:(CSIncident *)newIncident  
{  
    if (incident != newIncident)  
    {  
        [incident release];  
        incident = [newIncident retain];  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Note that an access between release and retain inside the if would return a nil object.

Comment: Yes so I think you would recommend autoreleasing the object?

Comment: Yes, `[incident autorelease]; incident = newIncident;` or `id old = incident; incident = [newIncident retain]; [old release];` and you can add the `if` if you like. Or just delete the whole thing and use the method generated by @synthesize. The code generated is here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.2/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.m

Comment: @Jano Thanks for your comments and reference! I have to use my own setter (and not the synthesized one) because it is more complex than the example I printed above. I just left the example simple for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have much value since you're manually controlling the set behavior and retaining it manually.

The only (very minimal) value would be readability to understand the behavior when you're just looking at the header and less churn if you remove the manual implementation (but you already have to remove setter=).

In your question you also have a mismatch between setDog and setIncident

Comment: @brynanmac THanks for the answer and for point out the (now fixed) mismatch.